# Proteção Simples em formulário para evitar Spam

Tags: html

Eu tenho o seguinte formulário:

```
  <!-- Comments Form -->
          <div class="card my-4">
            <h5 class="card-header">Deixar um comentário</h5>
            <div class="card-body">
<!-- Comentar -->
              <form method="post">
                  <input type="hidden" name="telefone" value="<?php echo $_GET['aluno']; ?>">

                     <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="control-label">Nome</label>
                          <input name="nome" type="text" class="form-control" required placeholder="Nome">
                     </div>

                     <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="control-label">Classificação</label>
                          <select name="classificacao" class="form-control">
                              <option>Usuário?</option>
                              <option value="1">1</option>
                          </select>
                     </div>

                     <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="control-label">Comentário</label>
                          <textarea name="comentario" class="form-control" placeholder="Comentario"></textarea>
                     </div>

                     <div class="form-group">
                          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Enviar comentário">
                     </div>
              </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Eu gostaria de adicionar um campo com uma soma para evitar SPAM.

Ex: Quanto é 2+3? se a resposta for 5 deixa enviar o comentário, caso contrário o comentário não é enviado.

Comment: https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Basic-Math-Captcha-Plugin.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma forma simples seria criar um campo `name="soma"` onde o usuário deverá inserir o valor da soma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os números você pode gerar randomicamente pelo PHP usando a função `rand(from,to)`, onde *from* é o número inicial e *to* o número final (ex.: `rand(1,9)` irá gerar um número inteiro randômico de 1 a 9).

No formulário, você inclui um novo `form-group` acima do botão "Enviar":

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label">Quanto é <span class="captcha"><?php echo(rand(1,9)); ?></span>+<span class="captcha"><?php echo(rand(1,9)); ?></span>?</label>
   <input name="soma" type="text" class="form-control" required>
</div>
```

Veja que incluí os dois números em dois `<span>` com a classe `.captcha` para pegar esses valores no jQuery, e comparar com o valor inserido no campo `"soma"` pelo usuário. Para isso usei um evento `onsubmit`. Quando o formulário for enviado, o script irá verificar se a soma está correta. Se não estiver, ele aborta o submit no `return false;`:

```
$("form").on("submit", function(){
   var s1 = parseInt($(".captcha:eq(0)").text()); // valor do 1º número
   var s2 = parseInt($(".captcha:eq(1)").text()); // valor do 2º número
   var ss = parseInt($("[name='soma']").val()); // valor da soma

   if(s1+s2 != ss){
      alert("Soma incorreta!");
      return false;
   }

   alert("Envia o formulário normal...");
});
```

**Código completo:**

```
<!-- Comments Form -->
<div class="card my-4">
   <h5 class="card-header">Deixar um comentário</h5>
   <div class="card-body">
      <!-- Comentar -->
      <form method="post">
         <input type="hidden" name="telefone" value="<?php echo $_GET['aluno']; ?>">

         <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Nome</label>
            <input name="nome" type="text" class="form-control" required placeholder="Nome">
         </div>

         <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Classificação</label>
            <select name="classificacao" class="form-control">
               <option>Usuário?</option>
               <option value="1">1</option>
            </select>
         </div>

         <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Comentário</label>
            <textarea name="comentario" class="form-control" placeholder="Comentario"></textarea>
         </div>

         <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Quanto é <span class="captcha"><?php echo(rand(1,9)); ?></span>+<span class="captcha"><?php echo(rand(1,9)); ?></span>?</label>
            <input name="soma" type="text" class="form-control" required>
         </div>

         <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Enviar comentário">
         </div>
      </form>
   </div>
</div>
<script>
$("form").on("submit", function(){
   var s1 = parseInt($(".captcha:eq(0)").text()); // valor do 1º número
   var s2 = parseInt($(".captcha:eq(1)").text()); // valor do 2º número
   var ss = parseInt($("[name='soma']").val()); // valor da soma

   if(s1+s2 != ss){
      alert("Soma incorreta!");
      return false;
   }

   alert("Envia o formulário normal...");
});
</script>
```

> Mas esta é apenas a parte do lado-cliente. É bom sempre validar também
>   no lado-servidor. Como a pergunta se refere apenas a **enviar ou não o formulário**, validar no lado-servidor pode ser assunto para uma outra pergunta.